# How to fake "Multitouch" for Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile, multi-touch

Here's the idea:

I have two panels that have MouseDown events. The idea I had was to have a timer that would enable and disable the panels alternatively every tenth of a second.

I was hoping that the MouseDown event would be caught by one panel and then I could read the e.X and e.Y of the event, and then the MouseDown event would be caught by another panel the next timer event.

This would be true MultiTouch but it might be enough to have some fun. But this doesn't work in practice.

My assumption is this technique is prevent from working at the hardware level. But I wanted to make sure nobody else had an idea on how to accomplish the "Hack Multitouch"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that it's just not going to work.

For multitouch you have to have the hardware to support it (capacitive tocuhscreen).  There's simply no way to make a resistive touchscreen (what's on your WinMo device) "see" two touches.  Instead it just provides the average of all touches.

I have seen a hack that assumes you don't touch both points at one time and that one point (upper left usually) never moves.  You can then figure out where the second point is by backing out from the average.  It sort-of worked for things like "zoom out" and "zoom in" type gestures, but that's about it.

Even if you have a capacitive touchscreen, unless the OS knows how to handle the mouse being at two positions at any given time, or the touchpanel driver explicitly provides the app with that info, you're still out of luck.

Comment: I figured that must be the issue. I was hoping that I could reset the screen and hopefully grab a random mousedown and then calculate it over time. Basically I have two regions of the screen one for each player. But the lowest MouseDown always win until it releases, which sucks.

If I could capture MouseDown's randomly and end them every so often then I could have a virtual MultiTouch at least over different areas of the screen. See what I'm going for there? Still certain it is impossible. It would be awesome!

Comment: Yes, I see what you are thinking, it just would require bending the laws of physics to get it to work.  Without hardware support, you just can't get there.

Comment: Thanks Chris1 It is helpful to know it is impossible so I don't waste anymore time on it.